# Как извлечь кусок из текста по названию пункта

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, dataset

Решаю такую задачу 
У меня есть большой тренировочный набор данных, где содержится:

- ID документа
- Текст документа

А так же, название оного из двух пунктов, к которому он относится:
**"обеспечение исполнения контракта"** или **"обеспечение гарантийных обязательств"**,
Это входные данные. 
На выходе нужно получить предложение из текста и номер начала и конца этого текста.
Вот пример такого обучающего набора данных

> id документа - 372681698
>
> текст документа -
>
> Извещение о
> проведении ЗАПРОСА КОТИРОВОК в электронной форме, участниками которого
> могут быть только субъекты малого и среднего предпринимательства
> Директор ГАПОУ СО «Уральский радиотехнический колледж им. А.С. Попова»
> _________________ Н. Т. чиком: 11 сентября 2022 г. (23:00). Обеспечительные меры 1 Обеспечение заявки Размер обеспечения заявки:
> 0% от НМЦД Обеспечение не устанавливается, если начальная
> (максимальная) цена договора не превышает пять миллионов рублей. В
> случае если НМЦД превышает пять миллионов рублей, заказчик вправе
> установить в документации о закупке требование к обеспечению заявок в
> размере от 0,5 до 5% от НМЦД. Способ обеспечения заявки: 1) путем
> внесения денежных средств на специальный счет; 2) путем предоставления
> банковской гарантии. Выбор способа обеспечения заявки осуществляется
> участником закупки самостоятельно. Возврат участнику закупки
> обеспечения заявки не производится в следующих случаях: 1) уклонение
> или отказ участника закупки от заключения договора; 2)
> непредоставление или предоставление с нарушением условий,
> установленных Федеральным законом от 18 июля 2011 года № 223-ФЗ, до
> заключения договора заказчику обеспечения исполнения договора (при
> необходимости). 2 Обеспечение исполнения договора Размер обеспечения
> исполнения договора: 0% от НМЦД Заказчик вправе установить обеспечение
> исполнения договора в размере до 30% НМЦД, но не менее размера аванса.
> Способ обеспечения заявки: 1) путем внесения денежных средств; 2)
> путем предоставления банковской гарантии. Выбор способа обеспечения
> заявки осуществляется участником закупки самостоятельно. В случае
> частичного исполнения договора поставщик (подрядчик, исполнитель)
> вправе предоставить заказчику обеспечение исполнения договора,
> уменьшенное на размер исполненных обязательств, предусмотренных
> договором, взамен ранее предоставленного обеспечения исполнения
> договора. При этом может быть изменен способ обеспечения исполнения
> договора. Порядок предоставления: Документы, подтверждающие
> предоставление обеспечения исполнения договора, предоставляются
> победителем одновременно с подписанным проектом договора (без подписи
> заказчика) в порядке и сроки, предусмотренные Положением о закупке.
> Договор заключается после предоставления участником закупки, с которым
> заключается договор, обеспечени При расторжении договора в связи с
> односторонним отказом заказчика от исполнения договора по вине
> поставщика (подрядчика, исполнителя) заказчик вправе потребовать от
> поставщика (подрядчика, исполнителя) возмещения причиненных
> убытков.",

**Название пункта** - *обеспечение исполнения контракта* 
На выходе нужно получить следующий кусок текста -

> Размер обеспечения исполнения договора: 0% от НМЦД 
> Ну и данные начала,
> конца текста - 1243, 1293

Я проанализировав обучающие данные пришел к выводу, что итоговый кусок текста должен содержать полностью название пункта - все слова и в предложение должны быть точные величины - цифры, проценты, денежная стоимость 
Я решаю это с помощью **sklearn**, но не могут понять какой метод использовать и в каком направлении двигаться. 
Решаю это на Python. 
**Это должна быть модель, использующая машинное обучение** 
Прошу помочь-посоветовать как решается такая задача

Comment: Покажите что именно у вас не получается, ваши наработки.

Comment: Фрагменты кода не смогу показать, но я пробовал линейный классификатор - но потом понял, что вообще не о том. Потом узнал про задачу реферирование текста и пробовал метод Луна - но результат был не тот. Теперь узнал про реферирование по эталону и узнаю про SummaRuNNer